# State of variable not binding

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
<button id="btn1"> Button 1 </button>
<button id="btn2" v-if="state == 2"> Button 2 </button>

 export default {
        data() {
            return {
                emailPreferences: {
                    isLoading: false
                },
                state: 0 
            }
        },
       methods: {

        OnBtn1Click() {
            this.state = 2;
        }
      }
  }
```

I'm trying to show the button "btn2" when I click the Button 1.  But it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: You don't appear to have registered a `click` listener on the button. `@click="OnBtn1Click"`.

Comment: haha obviously ... :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting @skirtle's comment in an awnser:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    state: 0 
  },
  methods: {
    OnBtn1Click() {
      this.state = 2;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="OnBtn1Click" id="btn1"> Button 1 </button>
  <button id="btn2" v-if="state == 2"> Button 2 </button>
</div>
```

The logic of your code was fine, just had the 'onclick' property missing for the button

Answer (score 1):

**Add a click event on the button**

```
<button @click="OnBtn1Click" id="btn1"> Button 1 </button>
```